# android get Stacktrace from native code in LogCat

Tags: android, native, crash-reports, android-logcat

When native part(C++, Qt) of my program crashed I see in logcat some stacktrace. But this messages don't have application name, only "DEBUG" tag. That's why I can not get it for sending crash report (I use ACRA) beacuse "since JellyBean logcat provides only traces from your own app"
How I can get it or do that they were writing in the name of my application?

Sorry for my bad english,
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could use the following way (checkout [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/android-ndk/1sXo8l8e5UM)): 
create header with the following content:

```
#include <android/log.h>

#define LOGV(...) __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_VERBOSE, "libnav",
__VA_ARGS__)
#define LOGD(...) __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG  , "libnav",
__VA_ARGS__)
#define LOGI(...) __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO   , "libnav",
__VA_ARGS__)
#define LOGW(...) __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_WARN   , "libnav",
__VA_ARGS__)
#define LOGE(...) __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR  , "libnav",
__VA_ARGS__)

#endif // ANDROID_ALOG_H
```

or just use `__android_log_print` directly.

Comment: It was already asked here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8415032/catching-exceptions-thrown-from-native-code-running-on-android

Comment: Thanks but it is not what I had in mind. I have this function already, but they don't use by system libraries that print stacktrace in SIGSEGV handler for example...  I can set my handler for SIGSEGV but don't know how get stacktrace from it...

Comment: oh, so it seems to be continue of https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/android-developers/6U4A5irWang/8ar5-9lLmaAJ discussion