# How can I get the Android exception in native layer?

Tags: android, exception, logcat

for example, I want my APP to uplode the following exception.

Espicaially **the top 2 lines**, not just java exception.

```
E/SQLiteLog(10757): (14) cannot open file at line 30178 of [00bb9c9ce4]
E/SQLiteLog(10757): (14) os_unix.c:30178: (2) open(/data/data/com.efei.testdb/databases/myDB.db) - 
E/SQLiteDatabase(10757): Failed to open database '/data/data/com.efei.testdb/databases/myDB.db'.
E/SQLiteDatabase(10757): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database
E/SQLiteDatabase(10757):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeOpen(Native Method)
E/SQLiteDatabase(10757):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:209)
E/SQLiteDatabase(10757):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:193)
E/SQLiteDatabase(10757):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:463)
E/SQLiteDatabase(10757):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:185)
E/SQLiteDatabase(10757):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:177)
E/SQLiteDatabase(10757):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:804)
E/SQLiteDatabase(10757):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:789)
E/SQLiteDatabase(10757):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:694)
E/SQLiteDatabase(10757):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:669)
E/SQLiteDatabase(10757):    at com.efei.testdb.MainActivity.getInfo(MainActivity.java:120)
E/SQLiteDatabase(10757):    at com.efei.testdb.MainActivity$QueryThread.run(MainActivity.java:46)
```

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: This question has some pretty good answers. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8415032/catching-exceptions-thrown-from-native-code-running-on-android

Comment: Thanx ~~ But I can not change or edit JNI, because I want to obtain SQLITE information ...