# Exception Handling: how can I catch C++ exception in Java

Tags: java, c++, exception, java-native-interface

EDITED:
I have an implementation of some C++ code in Java using **SWIG.** The C++ function throws an exception which I am unable to catch in Java. The **JVM crashes** whenever the exception is reached.

**Java:**

```
try 
{
    myNativeClass = new myNativeClass();        
} 
catch (Throwable t) 
{
    System.out.println("There was an error in intializing myNativeClass");
}
```

The JNI call is of the form: `public final static native long new_myNativeClass();`

**C:**

```
class myNativeClass 
{
    public:

    myNativeClass()
    {
        doSomthing();
    };
}
```

---

```
void myNativeClass::doSomthing()
{
  /*
    something nasty occurred here
  */ 
   throw -1;
}
```

Comment: Not quite a dupe, but close: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4138168/1076640 tldr: You can't, so you should instead have the c++ code queue up a Java exception to get thrown.

Comment: Translate it to a Java exception before returning back up to Java.

Comment: Translate first to a Java exception. Can you give me some guidance on how to do this?

Comment: You need to look up the JNI API. There are JNI methods to throw Java exceptions.

Comment: I have it working now. In C++ code, do this: throw `std::runtime_error("error occured in C++ code.");` And in Swig definition for JNI, do this: `%include exception.i 
%exception {
  try {
    $action
  } catch (const std::exception& e) {
    SWIG_exception(SWIG_RuntimeError, e.what());
  }
}` And in Java, use _try - catch_ as usual. I couldn't' provide the answer in the Answers section since the question has been marked complete, but this solution could be useful to many -- especially if they are using **SWIG**. So maybe consider reopening question as "non-duplicate".